# How to use LINQ to order a file name by a substring using a condition?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, linq-to-sql

I have some Excel (.xlsx) files in a folder and its subfolders that I'm trying to list on my website. The file names have the following format:

```
2018_MyData_Day.xlsx
2018_MyData_Month.xlsx
2018_MyData_Year.xlsx
2019_MyData_Day.xlsx
2019_MyData_Month.xlsx
2019_MyData_Year.xlsx
```

*Note: `Day`, `Month`, and `Year` are text, not a placeholder for an actual numeric day, month, or year (in case that was misleading).*

I need to display these file names with a descending file name, but grouped by `Year`, `Day`, or `Month` in that specific order. So, the output, using the list above, should be:

```
2019_MyData_Year.xlsx
2018_MyData_Year.xlsx

2019_MyData_Day.xlsx
2018_MyData_Day.xlsx

2019_MyData_Month.xlsx
2018_MyData_Month.xlsx
```

I used the following to sort the file name by year and by the `Day`, `Month`, `Year` substring, but the substring is not ordered correctly:

```
var fileGroup = (
    from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(myPath, searchPattern: "*.xlsx", searchOption: SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    let fileName = Path.GetFileName(file)
    orderby fileName descending
    select fileName
).OrderBy(f => f.Substring(f.LastIndexOf("_")))
```

I'm sure I need a condition since the desired order is custom, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Is this even possible or is there a better way to achieve my desired output?

Thanks!

Comment: First of all you should group your "string" just like you wrote in question and your code is not grouping your collection.

Comment: So _year, _month, and _day are fixed suffixes in the filename (I'm not sure if i got this right)? If so you can split the files into three lists and order these ==> filelist.Where(i => i.EndsWith("_year").OrderByDescending(i => i);

Comment: @MichałK. - I think that's what I'm having trouble with. I'm not sure how to group the `Year`, `Day`, and `Month` in that specific order.

Comment: @Martin - Yes, "_Year", "_Day", and "_Month" are fixed text suffixes. The file name is exactly as it appears in the question, as opposed to being something like "2019_MyData_2012.xlsx". For your suggestion, I would have to write three separate statements, correct? I was hoping to do this in one statement, if possible.

Comment: @user2063351 See my answer then:)

Comment: @user2063351 did any of the replies provided you with an answer?, if so please mark it :) 
Hope we helped you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do that using some let:

```
var fileGroup = (from f in Directory.GetFiles(myPath, "201*.xlsx")
                let fName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f)
                let ymd = fName.Substring("2000_MyData_".Length).ToLower()
                 let fOrder = (ymd == "year" ? 0 : ymd == "day" ? 1 : 2)
                 select new {f, year=int.Parse(fName.Substring(0,4)), o=fOrder})
                .OrderBy(g => g.o)
                .ThenByDescending(g => g.year)
                .Select(g => g.f);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a Select where you project the filename to two properties:

- FileYear: 2018, 2019, everything until the first underscore
- FilePeriod: an int where (0) = year, (1) = Day, (2) = Month, the part after the second underscore

.

```
var underscore = new char[] {'_'};
var orderedFiles = originalFiles.Select(fileName =>
{
    // TODO: decide what to do if filename incorrect format
    var splitFileName = fileName.Split(underscore);

    int filePeriod;
    switch (splitFileName[2])
    {
        case "Year":
            filePeriod = 0;
            break;
        case "Day":
            filePeriod = 1;
            break;
        case "Month":
            filePeriod = 2;
            break;
        default:
            filePeriod = 3;
            break;
    }

    return new
    {
        FileYear = Int32.Parse(splitFileName[0]),
        FilePeriod = filePeriod,
        OriginalFileName = fileName,
    };
})

// sort:
.OrderBy(splitFile => splitFile.FileYear)
.ThenBy(splitFile => splitFile.FilePeriod)

// back to original filename
.Select(splitFile => splitFile.OriginalFileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use LINQ as follows.

```
var list = new []{
    "2018_MyData_Day.xlsx",
    "2018_MyData_Month.xlsx",
    "2018_MyData_Year.xlsx",
    "2019_MyData_Day.xlsx",
    "2019_MyData_Month.xlsx",
    "2019_MyData_Year.xlsx"
     };

    var result = list.GroupBy(x=> new { Type= x.Split(new[]{"_"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[2]})
                     .Select(x=> new {Key = x.Key, FullName = x.OrderBy(c => c)});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var fileGroup = (from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(myPath, searchPattern: "*.xlsx", searchOption: SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            let fileName = Path.GetFileName(file)
            select fileName)
            .GroupBy(f => f.Substring(f.LastIndexOf("_") + 1))
            .Select(x => x.OrderBy(y => y));
```

I Think this might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(myPath, searchPattern: "*.xlsx", searchOption: SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(x => Path.GetFileName(x));

Regex reg = new Regex(".*_(?<dmy>Day|Month|Year)\\.xlsx");
var groups = files.GroupBy(x => reg.Match(x).Groups["dmy"].Value);
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var g in groups.OrderBy(x => x.Key == "Year" ? 0 : x.Key == "Day" ? 1 : 2))
{
    builder.AppendLine();
    foreach(var f in g.OrderByDescending(x => x))
    {
        builder.AppendLine(f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try changing your code to become:

```
var fileGroup = (
from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(myPath, searchPattern: "*.xlsx", searchOption: SearchOption.AllDirectories)
let fileName = Path.GetFileName(file)
let fileParts = fileName.Split('.')[0].Split('_')
orderby fileParts[2] descending, fileParts[0] descending
select fileName
)
```